# Add filters from the filter dialog to the view

Tags: c#, api, revit

Does anybody know how to access and add the filters from the filters tab in the Visibilty Graphics from the Revit API in C#? I am using versie 2014 of the API. In the second screenshot the list is empty but in my revit project it is filled with filters.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
FilteredElementCollector viewCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
viewCollector.OfClass(typeof(FilterElement));
```

the FilterElements in the collection are the ones in the dialog describe in my question.